# Parse push notification via REST api is not sent to iOS device

Tags: ios, rest, parse-platform, push-notification

I cannot receive push notification to iOS device via REST api with a procedure below.

1. Registered iOS device token like this

   ```
   - (void)setupParseWithApplication:(UIApplication *)application {
       [Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APP_ID
                     clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];
       // Register for Push Notitications
       if(isOSLessThan(@"8.0")) {
           UIRemoteNotificationType remoteNotificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                               UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                               UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound);
           [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:remoteNotificationTypes];
       } else {
           UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                           UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                           UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
           UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                    categories:nil];
           [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
           [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
       }
   }

   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
       // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
       NSLog(@"%@", deviceToken.description);
       PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
       [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
       currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];

       [[currentInstallation saveInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
           NSLog(@"%@", task.result);
           return task;
       }];
   }
   ```
2. Used REST api

`#/bin/sh
    curl -X POST \
      -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
      -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceToken": {
            "$in": [
              "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" (device token obtained in 1, space and <> are removed)
            ]
          }
        },
        "data": {
                  "alert": "Push",
                  "badge": "Increment"
                }
        }' \
        https://api.parse.com/1/push`

With above, push notification log was left in Parse console as attached, but not this push notification was not delivered.
Could you please tell me what is wrong with this procedure?

Comment: Have you tried sending a notification to the device from parse itself?

Comment: Yes, I tried to send push notification with Parse console to all registered device, and it worked well. But REST api does not work as above.

Comment: Have you tried registering the device on a specific channel and sending it to that?

Comment: Yes, I tried to send to "global" channel via REST api, and it worked well. But adding device token, it did not work.